Unable to read pom.xml inside META-INF folder of Spring war deployed on Tomcat
I am trying to read pom.xml file as I need get list of dependencies.
When I run SpringBoot application using STS or Eclipse, I am able to read file using below line as POM file is present inside project folder.
Model model = mavenXpp3Reader.read(new FileReader("pom.xml"));

When I run SpringBoot application as jar e.g., java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=local my-app-1.0.0.war, I am able to read file using below line code snippet
Model model = mavenXpp3Reader.read(new InputStreamReader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                    .getResourceAsStream("META-INF/maven/{groupId}/{artifactId}/pom.xml")));

and also using below snippet
Model model = mavenXpp3Reader.read(new InputStreamReader(
                    this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/maven/{groupId}/{artifactId}/pom.xml")));

However, if I deploy this application WAR on Tomcat, none of these are working.
I tried with using \ before path and using / also in path. But none of these are working.
I also tried with /webapps/xyz#services/META-INF/maven/{groupId}/{artifactId}/pom.xmlas I found this is the full path of pom.xml on Tomcat
I think the approaches I used will read only inside classpath e.g,. classes not inside webapps folder.
Right now I have no clue what is wrong with this code. Any clue or help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Why are you reading the pom from MET-INF? This could an XY Problem. You should provide more clarity into what are you trying to achieve, what is the original problem you are trying to resolve.

Why are you trying to read the pom.xml... ?

@aled I am trying to get list of dependencies.

@khmarbaise to get list of dependencies

Why do you need them within your application?

@khmarbaise we have a health check endpoint in our application and we have to provide list of dependencies used by application for some group id along with their version

If you are using Spring Boot you don't need those information just use the provided health check... You can generate the information up-front during the build process.. (maybe things like maven-dependency-plugin:list or alike etc.)

If you like to have a predefined one use Spring Boot 3.3.0 it already has an SBOM endpoint https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.3-Release-Notes#sbom-actuator-endpoint

If I need to obtain all the dependent jar files defined in pom.xml, I will execute command :  mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=target/libs      Then I can see all the dependent jars in the libs directory. But like others, I don't understand why it is necessary to read all pom.xml files during execution.

Try using the Spring Framework FileSystemResource to use a file given it's path:
Resource resource = new FileSystemResource("/extact-path-to-file");
Model model = mavenXpp3Reader.read(resource.getInputStream());


Thanks for giving your time in answering that but its not working from me. It looks like this approach will work only if files are inside classes folder of exploded WAR. I probably need solution to read it from /webapps/xyz#services/META-INF/ but not /classes/META-INF

I modified the answer for when you have the exact path.
